Синонимизировать метки [yandex-maps-api] и [yandex-maps-jsapi] и [яндекс-карта-api]
yandex-maps-jsapi - отличие лишь в наличии js - если и есть не-js кейсы, мне они не попадались среди вопросов. И в итоге yandex-maps-api в том числе включат js.
яндекс-карта-api- тут понятно - русскоязычный синоним.
yandex-maps-api - 1,548 вопросов
yandex-maps-jsapi - 472 вопроса
яндекс-карта-api - 69 вопросов
И вот есть тема о приоритете русскоязычных меток для яндекс. С этой точки зрения не уверена какая метка должна быть основной - но можно заметить - англоязычный вариант более распространен.
Сделать синонимами метки, удалить и переименовать кучу меток на тему яндекса (раз уж решили, что яндексовские метки должны быть на русском)

Интересный момент ещё: яндекс же вроде разделился (или в процессе), кому какие API достались?
